# Alteration of two values in R Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, comparison, string-comparison

Originally I have the first four columns. There are two players A and B in Round 1 and ROund 2. And maximum score for each round is 1.

In the fifth column(which I want to get), I would like to have how much alteration(score changing) of player A in second round compared to initial score1.

Such that, in the 3rd row, for round 2, B has 0.855, and A has (1-0.855)=0.145. Of it, the alteration of A from the initial score is -0.855.

[image]

The example data is generated by this:
 '''

```
set.seed(123)
Round1 <- sample("A", size=10, replace = T, prob = NULL)
Score1 <- sample(seq(0.71,1,length.out = 3), size=10, replace = T, prob = NULL)
Score2 <- sample(seq(0.71,1,length.out = 3),size = 10, replace = T)
Round2 <- sample(LETTERS[1:2],size = 10,replace = T)
d <- data.frame(Round1,Score1,Round2,Score2)
```

Can anybody help me writing better?
I tried this but doesn't really give what I expected:

```
d$Alteration <- ifelse(d$Round1==d$Round2, -1*(d$Score1-d$Score2),ifelse(d$Round1!=d$Round2 & d$Score2==1, -1+d$Score1, -1*d$Score2))
```

Comment: Please add expected output to your question.

Comment: How exactly do you calculate `Alteration` column?

Comment: The expected output is as in column fifth "alteration",, I tried to solve it by command in the last line, but doesn't give what I expected.

Comment: OK, but as @RonakShah asks, perhaps explaining the math you use, imagining you were doing this with good old pen and pencil; what would that look like>

Comment: As I tried to explain above: Such that, in the 3rd row, for round 2, B has 0.855, and A has (1-0.855)=0.145. Of it, the alteration of A from the initial score is -0.855. Because in first round A has 1 and in second round it has 0.145. so, for A, score1+alteration=score2 equal to 1+(-0.855)=0.145

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the alteration from score1, I just make two intermediaries columns using ifelse function. col A is intended for score2 if round1 and round2 have the same value. col B is current score of A in round2 if round1 and round2 have different values. Then, the alteration of A from score1 to score2 is calculated as follow

```
set.seed(123)
Round1 <- sample("A", size=10, replace = T, prob = NULL)
Score1 <- sample(1, size=10, replace = T, prob = NULL)
Score2 <- sample(seq(0.71,1,length.out = 3),size = 10, replace = T)
Round2 <- sample(LETTERS[1:2],size = 10,replace = T)
d <- data.frame(Round1,Score1,Round2,Score2)
d$Round1  <- as.character(d$Round1)
d$Round2 <- as.character(d$Round2)
d$A <- ifelse(d$Round1==d$Round2, d$Score2, 0)
d$B <- ifelse(d$Round1!=d$Round2, 1-d$Score2, 0)
d$Alteration <- ifelse(d$A!=0, d$A-d$Score1, d$B-d$Score1)
d
```

First six outputs:

```
>Round1 Score1 Round2 Score2     A     B Alteration
> A     1.000      B  1.000   0.000 0.000 -1.000
> A     0.855      B  1.000   0.000 0.000 -0.855
> A     1.000      B  0.855   0.000 0.145 -0.855
> A     0.855      B  1.000   0.000 0.000 -0.855
> A     0.710      A  0.855   0.855 0.000  0.145
> A     1.000      A  1.000   1.000 0.000  0.000
```